# Getting error while including prototype.js using Rails 3 in IE8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working in Rails 3.  If I run my application in IE8, I am getting the following error:

> "Internet Explorer has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience."

I tried few technical solutions but they didn't work.

Afterwards I removed prototype.js and the error was removed. If I include prototype.js again, the error gets displayed again.

Strange! What could be the solution?

Comment: What prototype are you using on the site?

Comment: Prototype JavaScript framework, version 1.7_rc2
Which comes with Rails 3 project's javascript folder

Answer (score 0):

give a try to Prototype 1.7RC3, it fixed a problem for me. Maybe it will help you too.